# Sending notification email using nodemailer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I have application built using angularjs and nodejs where the admin has to get a mail  about the details form the contact us from of the application

I am using nodemailer for it but i not able to figure out  how to send the details entered by the user coming from the request in the mail body am getting has req.body.name but excepted is the name of the user(eg:sam)

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
  service: "Gmail",  // sets automatically host, port and connection security settings
  auth: {
    user: "dhanalakshmi.05k@gmail.com",
    pass: "*****"
  }
});

router.route('/sendmail')
  .post(function(req,res){
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1");
    console.log(req.body);
    smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
    from: "dhanalakshmi.05k@gmail.com", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
    to: "dhanalakshmi@zendynamix.com", // receiver
    subject: "UsersQuery", // subject
    ***html: "<b style='color: #006600'>UserQuery</b><p>name:req.body.name</p><p>name:req.body.email</p><p>name:req.body.message</p>"***
    }, function(error, response){  //callback
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }else{
    console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
  }
  smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
});
    res.send("done");
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the variables outside the quotes and possibly change them:

```
html: '<b style="color: #006600">UserQuery</b><p>name:' + req.body.name + '</p><p>name:' + req.body.email + '</p><p>name:' + req.body.message + '</p>'
```

Use double quotes only for HTML attributes (style, class, id, etc...), use single quote for the rest.

Comment: Your `'<p>' + name:req.body.name +` segment won't work, I think the intent was to have `name` be part of the html. So `<p>name:' + req.body.name +`

Comment: Just making sure. Your answer was correct; I just couldn't help but add the template string answer. ES6/ES2015 examples whenever I can ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `node 4.0` or higher you should try [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) instead; you use backtick character instead of single or double quotes. This allows for multiline strings without having to add `"\n"` and a `+` at the end of each line.

This is much easier to read, also more cool!

```
html: `<b style='color: #006600'>UserQuery</b>
       <p>name: ${req.body.name}</p>
       <p>email: ${req.body.email}</p>
       <p>message: ${req.body.message}</p>`
```